# Weird heights and widths on input box in html css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to format an input box but im running into problems where the height of the input ends up being weird. When I look in the developer tools at the height the input isn't made up of clean numbers, instead it is made up of odd decimal figures, for example the border isn't 1px it's 0.909.

What is causing this, and how can I get back to clear, whole numbers.

```css
 input { padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 3px;}
```

```html
<form class="search left">
  <input class="input" placeholder="K">
  <input class="input" placeholder="L">
  <input type="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: i dont see any problems it may be a problem from the DevTools itself.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/w8pam78j/1/ do you see the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're zoomed in on your browser. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to reset the zoom level to 100%.

At 110% zoom level you will see something like this:

[image: Zoomed In]

Whereas at 100% you'll see what you're expecting:

[image: Normal Zoom Level]

Comment: Ah! That's it. I'm sorry it was something dumb

Comment: @Jimmy I was also zoomed in for whatever reason and it took me by surprise to see those results at first as well!